# Weird gradient results with recurrent layers

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, lasagne, recurrent-neural-network

I've been experimenting with very basic recurrent networks and have seen really strange behaviors. I've spent quite a bit of time trying to narrow down where it goes wrong and I ended up finding that the gradients computed by theano and by finite differentiation are radically different when using a recurrent layer. What is going on here?

Here is the kind of problem I have:

I have n_seq sequences of n_steps feature vectors of dimension n_feat, along with their labels among n_class classes. The labels are per time step, not per sequence (so I have n_seq*n_steps labels).
My goal is to train a model to correctly classify the feature vectors.

Here's my minimal example:

(In reality, there would be some sequential information in the data, hence recurrent networks should do better, but in this minimal example I generate purely random data, which is good enough to expose the bug.)

I create 2 minimal networks:

1) A regular feed-forward (not recurrent), with just the input layer and an output layer with softmax  (no hidden layer). I discard the sequential information by considering a "batch" of n_seq*n_steps "independent" feature vectors.

2) An identical network but where the output layer is recurrent. The batch is now of size n_seq and each input is a full sequence of n_steps feature vectors. Finally I reshape the output back to a "batch" of size n_seq*n_steps.

If the recurrent weights are set to 0, the 2 networks should be equivalent. Indeed I do see that the initial loss for both networks are the same in this case, no matter what random initialization for the feed-forward weights I have.
If I implement a finite differentiation, I also get that the (initial) gradients for the feed-forward weights are the same (as they should). However the gradients obtained from theano are radically different (but only for the recurrent network).

Here is my code with sample result:

NOTE: when run for the first time, I get this warning, I don't know what triggers it but I bet it is relevant to my problem.
Warning: In the strict mode, all neccessary shared variables must be passed as a part of non_sequences
  'must be passed as a part of non_sequences', Warning)

Any insight would be much appreciated!

CODE:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import lasagne


# GENERATE RANDOM DATA
n_steps = 10**4
n_seq = 10
n_feat = 2
n_class = 2
data_X = lasagne.utils.floatX(np.random.randn(n_seq, n_steps, n_feat))
data_y = np.random.randint(n_class, size=(n_seq, n_steps))

# INITIALIZE WEIGHTS
# feed-forward weights (random)
W = theano.shared(lasagne.utils.floatX(np.random.randn(n_feat,n_class)), name="W")
# recurrent weights (set to 0)
W_rec = theano.shared(lasagne.utils.floatX(np.zeros((n_class,n_class))), name="Wrec")
# bias (set to 0)
b = theano.shared(lasagne.utils.floatX(np.zeros((n_class,))), name="b")



def create_functions(model, X, y, givens):
    """Helper for building a network."""
    loss = lasagne.objectives.categorical_crossentropy(lasagne.layers.get_output(model, X), y).mean()
    get_loss = theano.function(
        [], loss,
        givens=givens
    )
    all_params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(model)
    get_theano_grad = [
        theano.function(
            [], g,
            givens=givens
        )
        for g in theano.grad(loss, all_params)
    ]
    return get_loss, get_theano_grad


def feedforward():
    """Creates a minimal feed-forward network."""
    l_in = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(
        shape=(n_seq*n_steps, n_feat),
    )
    l_out = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(
        l_in,
        num_units=n_class,
        nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.softmax,
        W=W,
        b=b
    )
    model = l_out
    X = T.matrix('X')
    y = T.ivector('y')
    givens={
        X: theano.shared(data_X.reshape((n_seq*n_steps, n_feat))),
        y: T.cast(theano.shared(data_y.reshape((n_seq*n_steps,))), 'int32'),
    }
    return (model,) + create_functions(model, X, y, givens)


def recurrent():
    """Creates a minimal recurrent network."""
    l_in = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(
        shape=(n_seq, n_steps, n_feat),
    )
    l_out = lasagne.layers.RecurrentLayer(
        l_in,
        num_units=n_class,
        nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.softmax,
        gradient_steps=1,
        W_in_to_hid=W,
        W_hid_to_hid=W_rec,
        b=b,
    )
    l_reshape = lasagne.layers.ReshapeLayer(l_out, (n_seq*n_steps, n_class))
    model = l_reshape
    X = T.tensor3('X')
    y = T.ivector('y')
    givens={
        X: theano.shared(data_X),
        y: T.cast(theano.shared(data_y.reshape((n_seq*n_steps,))), 'int32'),
    }
    return (model,) + create_functions(model, X, y, givens)


def finite_diff(param, loss_func, epsilon):
    """Computes a finitie differentation gradient of loss_func wrt param.""" 
    loss = loss_func()
    P = param.get_value()
    grad = np.zeros_like(P)
    it = np.nditer(P , flags=['multi_index'])
    while not it.finished:
        ind = it.multi_index
        dP = P.copy()
        dP[ind] += epsilon
        param.set_value(dP)
        grad[ind] = (loss_func()-loss)/epsilon
        it.iternext()
    param.set_value(P)
    return grad


def theano_diff(net, get_theano_grad):
    for p,g in zip(lasagne.layers.get_all_params(net), get_theano_grad):
        if p.name == "W":
            gW = np.array(g())
        if p.name == "b":
            gb = np.array(g())
    return gW, gb


def compare_ff_rec():
    eps = 1e-3 # for finite differentiation
    ff, get_loss_ff, get_theano_grad_ff = feedforward()
    rec, get_loss_rec, get_theano_grad_rec = recurrent()
    gW_ff_finite = finite_diff(W, get_loss_ff, eps)
    gb_ff_finite = finite_diff(b, get_loss_ff, eps)
    gW_rec_finite = finite_diff(W, get_loss_rec, eps)
    gb_rec_finite = finite_diff(b, get_loss_rec, eps)
    gW_ff_theano, gb_ff_theano = theano_diff(ff, get_theano_grad_ff)
    gW_rec_theano, gb_rec_theano = theano_diff(rec, get_theano_grad_rec)
    print "\nloss:"
    print "FF:\t", get_loss_ff()
    print "REC:\t", get_loss_rec()
    print "\ngradients:"
    print "W"
    print "FF finite:\n", gW_ff_finite.ravel()
    print "FF theano:\n", gW_ff_theano.ravel()
    print "REC finite:\n", gW_rec_finite.ravel()
    print "REC theano:\n", gW_rec_theano.ravel()
    print "b"
    print "FF finite:\n", gb_ff_finite.ravel()
    print "FF theano:\n", gb_ff_theano.ravel()
    print "REC finite:\n", gb_rec_finite.ravel()
    print "REC theano:\n", gb_rec_theano.ravel()


compare_ff_rec()
```

RESULTS:

```
loss:
FF:     0.968060314655
REC:    0.968060314655

gradients:
W
FF finite:
[ 0.23925304 -0.23907423  0.14013052 -0.14001131]
FF theano:
[ 0.23917811 -0.23917811  0.14011626 -0.14011627]
REC finite:
[ 0.23931265 -0.23907423  0.14024973 -0.14001131]
REC theano:
[  1.77408110e-05  -1.77408110e-05   1.21677476e-05  -1.21677458e-05]
b
FF finite:
[ 0.00065565 -0.00047684]
FF theano:
[ 0.00058145 -0.00058144]
REC finite:
[ 0.00071526 -0.00047684]
REC theano:
[  7.53380482e-06  -7.53380482e-06]
```

Comment: An RNN with 2 layers where the 2nd layer is both recurrent **and** softmax output seems very "weird" to me. Have you tried it with a proper 3-layer-architecture? Maybe that's where theano gets weird. The warning message you get is not an issue ([see here](http://colinraffel.com/talks/hammer2015recurrent.pdf)). It's a result of setting strict=True in theano.scan - I'm not sure how to change that through Lasagne though. It is also very possible that the change is simply due to your different input dimensions.

Comment: Nope, this is not the problem. Whether it is softmax or not, there will be a non-linearity applied anyway. The problem was the gradient_steps clipping in BPTT which is not acting the way I thought. See link in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming from non-intuitive (maybe) effect of gradient_steps clipping in BPTT as explained here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/QNge6fC6C4s